# force file_get_contents or stream_socket_client to use desired dns server

Tags: php

It's easy to bind `file_get_contents()` or `stream_socket_client()` to ip, but any idea how to force it to use desired dns to resolve domain names?

example:

```
$f = stream_socket_client("ssl://example.com:443",$errno,$errstr,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,stream_context_create(array('socket'=>array('bindto' => "192.168.1.1:0"),
```

But how do I force it to resolve `example.com` via given DNS?

The problem is that I can't connect to SSL via IP, because it says that CN is invalid and DNS server is not reliable. Found a solution for that though. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution to my problem. I guess my question wasn't clear enough, but the problem was with `CN` name while connecting to SSL server with an IP, as I couldn't resolve the ip from DNS correctly (dns server in the system often fails).

The solution is to add to a `context` under `ssl` section `peer_name`:

```
<?php
   stream_context_create(... 'ssl'=>array('peer_name' => 'example.com' ...)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` by itself is going to use the DNS settings that for the  the server it's installed on.  Since `php` doesn't have server level access, you'll have to use either your own bash/shell script and use something like `dig` or `nslookup` to acheive this (calling the `bash` / `shell` script with PHP's `exec()` or `shell_exec()` functions. -- Or there's a few libraries out there.  A popular one is [DNS2](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/redirected) built using `pear`.

So your options are:

1. Something like [DNS2](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/redirected)
2. A custom `bash` / `shell` script (in conjuction with `exec` or `shell_exec`)
3. Change the DNS settings locally on the machine `PHP` is installed
   on.

**NOTE**  One *could* also **simulate** this by entering static IP addresses into the hosts file of the machine that `PHP` is installed on.

Comment: maybe there is a way to resolve the name manually somehow? I mean - I know the IP, but server demands me to connect via hostname, system dns server sometimes won't return proper result

Comment: hmm maybe host header to the context would help

Comment: Use the hosts file ..   IE    `44.44.44.44     example.com`  In Linux `/etc/hosts`   --  In Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts\\`

Answer (score 0):

It should get DNS from the system it is running on, can you change local DNS of the PHP server?

Comment: the problem is more complicated, it's multi network system